# Golang Cannot Convert (type *string) to type string

Tags: string, go, type-conversion

When I tried to compile the following code I get following errors:

`users.go:31: cannot convert pass (type *string) to type string`

`users.go:78: cannot convert &user.Password (type *string) to type []byte`

How do I dereference or convert the pointer to the string literal?

Thanks in advance.

code which I am trying to compile: https://play.golang.org/p/gtMKLNAyNk

Comment: Can you also post the exact lines that are giving you issues in addition to your snippet. The lines don't match up so it's hard to know where the issue is.

Comment: Also add the models.User struct definition to your snippet, might be helpful

Comment: @shieldstroy here you go https://gist.github.com/itsbalamurali/e46d10acdceda906925d0e4836e9023f

Comment: You keep unnecessarily taking the address of things in that code. Hint, `&user.Username` will never be `nil`.

Comment: @JimB very new to this pointers thingy & go :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The if on line 9 needs to change I think. `user.Username` and `user.Password` are strings so they will never be nil. What you need to check instead is for empty string like this: `if user.Username != "" && user.Password != "" {`

`pass := &user.Password
password := []byte(*pass)`

Don't take the address of user.Password. Just use `password := []byte(user.Password)`

Basically all of your issues are variations on that theme.

Start fixing this issue by removing all `&` and `*` from your code and it will probably work (except for this one: `ctx.Get("database").(*gorm.DB)`)

Comment: No problem. Good luck! In general you can not worry too much about pointers until the compiler tells you that you need to. That's not entirely true but you'll get the hang of it.